# showing explicitly by separation of variables in polar coordinates that the green function can be expressed as Fourier series in azimuthal coordinate

Tags: electromagnetism

I am working on a problem in Jackson that asks me to show explicitly by separation of variables in polar coordinates that the green function can be expressed as Fourier series in azimuthal coordinate,

$G = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{-{\infty}}^{\infty} e^{i m (\phi - \phi')} g_m(\rho,\rho')$

where the radial green functions satisfy
$\frac{1}{\rho'}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}(\rho' \frac{\partial g_m}{\partial \rho'}) - \frac{m^2}{\rho'^2}g_m = -4 \pi \frac{\delta(\rho-\rho')}{\rho}$

I gather the problem wants me to literally do some kind of separation of variables.

Here is where I am taking this:

$\nabla^2 = \frac{1}{\rho'} \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}(\rho' \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}) - \frac{1}{\rho'^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi'^2}$ in polar coordinates

Ok then I think the delta function is something like $\frac{1}{\rho}\delta(\rho -\rho')\delta{(\phi - \phi')}$

Ok so setting it up I want to guess that it should be something like

$\nabla^2 G = (\frac{1}{\rho'} \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}(\rho' \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}) - \frac{1}{\rho'^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi'^2}) G = \frac{1}{\rho}\delta(\rho -\rho')\delta{(\phi - \phi')}$

where $G = \mathbf{R}(\rho)\Phi(\phi)$

It seems I would want to find a superposition of the homogeneous part and the part with a discontinuity.

At this point focusing on the homogeneous radial part,  I want to set the radial part to a constant say $\nu^2$ as is usually done.

One gets something like

$\frac{1}{\rho'}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}(\rho' \frac{dG}{d\rho'}) = \frac{m^2}{\rho'^2}$

$\frac{\rho}{R}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}(\rho' \frac{dR}{d\rho'}) = \nu^2$

Ok I am thinking to myself that one needs to then do next is to try to find

$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}(\rho' \frac{dG}{d\rho'}) -\frac{m^2}{\rho'^2}G =  \frac{1}{\rho}\delta(\rho -\rho')$

At which point I feel like throwing an integration sign on both sides

$\int \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}(\rho' \frac{dG}{d\rho'}) -\frac{m^2}{\rho'^2}G) d \rho' = \int  \frac{1}{\rho}\delta(\rho -\rho') d \rho'$

My hope was to try and get

i) the form $\frac{1}{\rho'}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho'}(\rho' \frac{\partial g_m}{\partial \rho'}) - \frac{m^2}{\rho'^2}g_m = -4 \pi \frac{\delta(\rho-\rho')}{\rho}$ How does one get this form?

ii)Also, now that I think about it after all this typing it seems like  $G = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{-{\infty}}^{\infty} e^{i m (\phi - \phi')} g_m(\rho,\rho')$ here is already of the form $G = \mathbf{R}(\rho)\Phi(\phi)$ and I just need to plug in and show that it works. Is that the case?